# Android Studio SimpleUMLCE doesn't add connectors

Tags: java, android, uml, class-diagram

so I'm new to this and I made this really simple chat application and wanted to see a UML class diagram and used SimpleUMLCE plugin on Android Studio to do it. The result is basically all my classes but none of them are connected to eachother only one of my classes is connected with an aggregation arrow to an other class. Also if I add extended classes they are then all connected to AppCompatActivity class. Can that be my actual UML class diagram or should I try using an other plugin?[image]